# Combine functions that perform the same type of action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions that perform virtually the same task, but on different elements. I only thought I would have two, but now I'm planning on adding more, so I'm noticing there will be a lot of redundancy. What can I do to improve my jQuery?

```
$('input#activity-view').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.action-view').show();
    } else {
        $('.action-view').hide();
    }
});

$('input#activity-upload').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.action-upload').show();
    } else {
        $('.action-upload').hide();
    }
});
```

The HTML is something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="activity-view"> View<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="activity-upload"> Upload<br />
<br />
<div class="action-upload">test</div>
<div class="action-upload">abc</div>
<div class="action-view">kk</div>
<div class="action-upload">yes</div>
```

**jsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/rLs82of1/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(':checkbox[id^="activity-"]').on('change', function() {
  var sel = '.action-' + this.id.split('-').pop();
  $(sel)[ this.checked ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
})
.change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="activity-view"> View<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="activity-upload"> Upload<br />
<br />
<div class="action-upload">test</div>
<div class="action-upload">abc</div>
<div class="action-view">kk</div>
<div class="action-upload">yes</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the selectors, delimit by comma

```
$('input#activity-upload, input#activity-view').change(function() {
```

Of course, you're going to have to run a check to make sure you're hiding/showing the proper classed element

Answer (score 0):

Just change your selector like this

```
$('input#activity-view,input#activity-upload').change( /* … */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rLs82of1/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var handleChange = function(elem, el) {
    var elem = $(elem), el = $(el);
    elem.change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            el.show();
        } else {
            el.hide();
        }
    });
};

handleChange('input#activity-view', '.action-view');
handleChange('input#activity-upload', '.action-upload');
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/xtm7n0hj/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the same name for the inputs id and divs class, then simply:

```
$('input').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(this.checked){
        $('.' + id).show();
    }else{
        $('.' + id).hide();
    }
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/rLs82of1/6/**